# using "pragma GCC optimize" in gfortran

Tags: fortran, directive, gfortran, pragma, fortran77

I'd like to use function specific option pragmas (like "#pragma GCC optimize("o3")" in C) in Fortran 77.
But, as I show following  I couldn't apply that to .f code. Any ideas?

foo.f:

```
     ...
     call hoge
     ... 
     subroutine hoge

     IMPLICIT REAL*4(a-h,o-z)
     ...
end
```

hoge.f:

```
     ...
     call hoge
     ...
!$pragma GCC optimize("O3")  
     subroutine hoge

     IMPLICIT REAL*4(a-h,o-z)
     ...
end
```

Terminal:

```
$ gfortran -O0 foo.f -o o0
$ gfortran -O0 hoge.f -o o3
$ cmp o0 o3
$
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. What makes you think such pragmas should be supported in Fortran? Did you find them in the manual? I do not think they are supported.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wanted to apply compiler options to each function in f77 in order to optimize the legacy code. when i searched how to do that, i found pragma GCC optimize directive for c language. I thought i can apply compiler options to f77 code using similar way.
 I'm not familiar with fortran77. so, if you have any ideas, please let me know.
Function Specific Option Pragmas (GCC):  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas

Comment: When trying unusual and undocumented features, it is good to at least have a *very good reason*. Why would you not use compiler flags and optimize the complete file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention of these directives in [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GNU-Fortran-Compiler-Directives.html). They are not supported in Fortran. Even if they were, the syntax would be different. In Fortran the directives use `!GCC$`, not `pragma`.